# Python: request url and get contents

Tags: python, url, python-requests, get, solana

I am trying to get transaction history for the following address `9QgXqrgdbVU8KcpfskqJpAXKzbaYQJecgMAruSWoXDkM` from the https://explorer.solana.com website.

I have tried

```
url="https://explorer.solana.com/address/9QgXqrgdbVU8KcpfskqJpAXKzbaYQJecgMAruSWoXDkM"
output = requests.get(url).text
print(output)
```

However this gives me raw html output.

How can I get the transactions from the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The history data is loaded from external URL via JavaScript. You can use `requests` module to simulate this call:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd


api_url = "https://explorer-api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/"

payload = {
    "id": "xxx",
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "getConfirmedSignaturesForAddress2",
    "params": ["9QgXqrgdbVU8KcpfskqJpAXKzbaYQJecgMAruSWoXDkM", {"limit": 25}],
}

data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(data["result"])
df["blockTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["blockTime"], unit="s")

print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| blockTime | confirmationStatus | err | memo | signature | slot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-30 12:36:01 | finalized |  |  | 4Pb3aMuiNGx1Xavj5GyeZHKAWvDp1BJAYXS3s1JjTx7uRr2qGNLGMkgPvicvMJGvKdt7gC5hTcDA822qu4th1MvR | 164077374 |
| 2022-11-23 13:05:04 | finalized |  |  | 5vWbZozXwTmNeqCwLDu8pgLKhf8gSbyAVuHamzDMGh3amYjtYZ5V647wkDigYQ4aRnSKNGNGzYYPtksHgYBeuF1b | 162708675 |
| 2022-10-17 17:37:48 | finalized |  |  | 2wYEAAZPBPu1ropcTV4k78BB6FbemhAQmnSRvRcuLHVz9j3Kh5tufMokJ5j3JsCsL8vRArUa3HtYP67bgNGJdLGk | 155859139 |
| 2022-09-18 09:34:45 | finalized |  | [209] Please consider to delegate with ManyStake in order to decentralize the solana network. OG delegator will be rewarded soon with extra MEV rewards. Our vote account AuBB9st3RqhHBkzZgBSm6SVnHZNJQSHeBWCSkik4bzdA | 48r1hcNHn4vw9kzd7fJnj4HWrLqzSsDfn6Ap6Dpbb2qwj6WL1xbYmah1CifVVBhwDZDqg6fsmUHqHW9t3m454pX8 | 151207313 |
| 2022-06-19 18:35:55 | finalized |  |  | 5v7T4aYM6dN9SK3V7Y6VS59aBcWabyNdyxLLJuKecZrTt2VqT1kW6MHobYxjGv4DHb8SYewB3Y1ZNhWML2pCFCGL | 138178511 |
| 2022-06-19 18:33:24 | finalized |  |  | 2ULTeYi3tqZi9xDtnPnNPYjYRGt8a8EcoAxZG2uGNkHvrNWiF3evbcSPmxN3LvGU9g1j8n9KYVqRmtzLTwhWfhr7 | 138178280 |
| 2022-06-19 18:19:04 | finalized |  |  | 4YnvsFtHPGzgijPB7KPEsBqj4o1ZigimhiPFuoyrCv8NLivVipNFp6RTmsNhkoeCYeDhWcK3ovkCqMmjYfQj711V | 138176965 |
| 2022-06-19 18:15:55 | finalized |  |  | EVTjZVQYghRK4bdMwCh6PnazRXZgSjCWvgu6XMqAiaEverkTNtkpfw2E7sRXPe973n1LnzmRnepNkCggLxZZS9S | 138176698 |
| 2022-06-19 17:55:54 | finalized |  |  | 2P9nSaGMfs2Daks9kGEnUp3R9UNpLZMFTudAjaVgDHJcwwxp1vDgfsn582bZb7HoDJTCrKCkBd3srcuUfXYAH1Tr | 138174836 |
| 2022-06-19 17:41:14 | finalized |  |  | 3Y7bmsHo3fTD3fqryPy37u6MMDGs9KGk7MLFbxw8sDx15j2sDPtRd4w8QjWWCoecLQQZHMT37Evt4D2oX1wd2sL | 138173447 |
| 2022-06-19 17:40:46 | finalized |  |  | 2ftBbaqKrMintETRxhH17HvDjEgX5W437BKZv8o4umeNXcs2B9WQJEm9kJEh2LfNeQMCgMkjDZXz8DziLMKvtHk3 | 138173398 |
| 2022-06-19 17:38:41 | finalized |  |  | 7Bdy3Ah78NmRmpbFsmKtFPiqrQGDpXZ2BBr83crivSso7wwbfVzEv4TrdpurYXWJV6X9j9hKfAvLWB3769GobJA | 138173207 |
| 2022-06-19 17:35:41 | finalized |  |  | 61iQ9BSQ18X54nT2ZzRCUtoUyXpTKS363QZFnXBgERAtUzLscpmj8oxTfrgxn7zwemNEKf1WB2yLhn3JgfmG96MY | 138172922 |
| 2022-06-19 17:32:16 | finalized |  |  | 5ueuPr4qZwHxhDSWRQHZkrNpTSDa6fR9LiGyokFJ1que6rpgRaSt9AX2S7L89KLztWKmehHKwxDpQywbvXbk6WQB | 138172617 |
| 2022-06-19 17:26:27 | finalized |  |  | EHRyD9ibJkt6cGgHbKbJqTuBj7bCzxeWGLBwuC8TgucvfKgv3ejqCRkG6sqUDVxQvsRWdGkQpagojRo2vajfDBa | 138172080 |
| 2022-06-19 17:25:59 | finalized |  |  | 3XxSXVQCKpZH48upHzYSj4nJyhWw6gpPiA6vPW8JyWwfniCh2Z29qokxQi2mtjyUiEWqthix6LKNBRpJhAQb2u8v | 138172029 |
| 2022-06-19 17:25:46 | finalized |  |  | 3DjUK7ENHYQLWGQ1Rw3bMqCjuzt4M6H1aPxWMVAU37vr2r64F2wXFgFsyeXqSiQ7JA1biQY691iwoEKDj5iztzg6 | 138172003 |
| 2022-06-19 17:25:14 | finalized |  |  | gQwiKLCuvvGDoEoniU6QR98PHTAMDyz7DVbxaYXRYWsPaC7Ekbyt9PDEpDNo7kueSddiN6V1jrwYoN3Rfir3x8w | 138171956 |
| 2022-06-19 17:22:02 | finalized |  |  | 52dFWxTaKL2h1MekafD12F3QWmnrDbsTxwEAMbZyiDhVNy7miVbwxX5d8NU7WioQpotG4uJ4txoFRRe2irRBqBfh | 138171653 |
| 2022-06-19 17:21:32 | finalized |  |  | 5yGwSWUZiaY5xAeSy5BFekJoSF3YiPiYh6GC5hyaPCDDQ3WEXWr9EzqWCf1g47ViUHekEMrsRDWuS8XN3k52hFVf | 138171595 |
| 2022-06-19 17:20:58 | finalized |  |  | 7SkpAQ1JNQYTUvR545pyWBQeHGEpisbgYxsUr1B2fnZm95CmGXUF4Y2UMVQbL1gbtd1mKaTTVCY3RBBpWcchaLD | 138171541 |
| 2022-06-19 17:20:38 | finalized |  |  | rsYUWj8irRFk15VxkFnjcJChDGyCmpe4MrCgrAyqt9ZoXoUcQsz7wiUKWYaU9qbds7V69jDxxhxbSzSJneJsfzA | 138171506 |
| 2022-06-19 17:20:12 | finalized |  |  | 4hjqfREeb22rSSuwHAZ5U3g2qZXVi4ejahZxBN95ecjfV3we1ELWP1ezJsCCaSnj9zygzzhWJrzZRpCHB3Nfcnw1 | 138171464 |
| 2022-06-19 17:09:47 | finalized |  |  | 2TXf2fwsYfCCTrkh4zfZSGhbEuZcLrKPwn8Ai4ZTpntKFS6FDU9YahRuT5cEYqYc1RJ5fMMkUtYtcbNv8ogAzVnM | 138170550 |
| 2022-06-19 17:09:31 | finalized |  |  | wDMRYiqHPNtYy6WJuA1kyaWjLr7RsnemnasEYufpaxdCmroNW4dBFLPLCQnYDnyZha9uZUSgbhC91zQT3E55bpP | 138170527 |

Comment: Is there a way to exceed the 1000 limit?

Comment: @MathMan99 That I don't know. It all depends how the API on the server is implemented.

Comment: @MathMan99 Looking at docs here: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getconfirmedsignaturesforaddress2  - maybe try `before` parameter, or other API call from the doc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked. I'll just have to iterate over the "first" signature looking backwards.